# Gridview Format Field as Phone Number but some results are 4 digit extensions, how to handle?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

So I am displaying the results from an SQL table in gridview. some Fields are phone numbers. A specific field may be a normal 10 digit number, but it also might be a 4 digit extension. If it's a 4 digit number, I want to at a minimum not put the 10 digit formatting on it, at a max I'd like to prepend it and say Ext: followed by my data. Here is what I have so far. I am not normally a programmer so this is Visual Studio wizards and google results cobbled together.
Thanks much for any assistance.

```
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>

    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"   AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <Columns>
           <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Call Destination" SortExpression="CallDestination">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CallDestination") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# String.Format("{0:(###) ###-####}",Convert.ToInt64(DataBinder.Eval (Container.DataItem, "CallDestination")))%>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:OnCallConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [TimeStamp], [CallerID], [Accepted], [CallDestination] FROM [OnCallLog]"></asp:SqlDataSource>

</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `RowDataBound` event to intercept each row as it is bound to the grid so you can determine if the phone number is 10 digits or 4 digits and handle each value on a case-by-case basis, like this:

Markup:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
     AutoGenerateColumns="False" onrowdatabound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
```

Note: Remove the `Text='<%# String.Format("{0:(###) ###-####}",Convert.ToInt64(DataBinder.Eval (Container.DataItem, "CallDestination")))%>'` from the `<asp:Label>` in `<ItemTemplate>`, because you will format your text and set the `Text` property in the `RowDataBound` event instead of declaratively.

Code-behind:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    // Only interested in each data row, not header or footer, etc.
    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        // Find the Label2 control in the row
        Lable theLabel = (Label)e.row.FindControl("Label2");

        // Make sure control is not null
        if(theLabel != null)
        {
            // Cast the bound to an object we can use to extract the value from
            DataRowView rowView = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;

            // Get the value for CallDestination field in data source
            string callDestinationValue = rowView["CallDestination"].ToString();

            // Find out if CallDestination is 10 digits or 4 digits
            if(callDestinationValue.Length == 10)
            {
                theLabel.Text = String.Format("{0:(###) ###-####}", Convert.ToInt64(rowView["CallDestination"]));
            }
            if(callDestinationValue.Length == 4)
            {
                theLabel.Text = "Ext: " + callDestinationValue;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Appreciate the help, I generally understand what is going on but am getting two of the same errors on compile:

'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRow.DataItem' cannot be used like a method

This is referring to this line:
     string newnumberValue = e.Row.DataItem("NewNumber").ToString();

and this one:
    theLabel.Text = String.Format("{0:(###) ###-####}", Convert.ToInt64(e.Row.DataItem("NewNumber")));

Any ideas?

Comment: Change it to use brackets instead, like this: `e.Row.DataItem["NewNumber"].ToString();`, see updated answer.

Comment: and i fixed it, don't know whether this is a must or not but added this line: DataRowView rowView = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem; and changed the e.Row.DataItem("NewNumber") to rowView["NewNumber"] and it works perfectly. Thanks again!

Comment: Also just noticed your comment and I had tried the brackets but with no success

Comment: @mloraditch - just going to suggest casting it to a `DataRowView`, sorry about leaving that step out, it has been awhile since I have done what you are trying to do. I will update the answer with the correct syntax.

Comment: @mloraditch - if you think my answer helped you, then feel free to up-vote and/or accept the answer. :-)